# Hadoop alternate SSH key

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I'm setting up a multinode hadoop cluster and have a shared key to passwordless SSH between nodes. I named the file `~/.ssh/hadoop_rsa` and can connect to other hosts using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/hadoop_rsa host`.

I need some way to tell hadoop to use this alternate SSH key when connecting to other nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that commands are run on each slave using the script:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/slaves.sh
```

That script includes a reference to the environment variable `$HADOOP_SSH_OPTS` when calling `ssh`. I was able to tell Hadoop to use a different key file by setting an environment variable like this:

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-i ~/.ssh/hadoop_rsa"
```

Thanks to Varun on the Hadoop mailing list for pointing me in the right direction